# Find all binary files in git HEAD

Tags: git

I have a huge git repo that eventually want to clean up with [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).
But first, I want to track down and remove files in the `HEAD` which git treats as binary...

So, what i'm looking for is a **command to find all files in the *HEAD* that git treats as binary**.

These didn't help:

- [List all text (non-binary) files in repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-repo) < I am looking for binary files. not text files.
- [Git find all binary files in history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931520/git-find-all-binary-files-in-history) < I only care about the HEAD
- http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-list-binary-and-or-non-binary-files-td3506370.html < I tried those commands and they don't help.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
diff <(git grep -Ic '') <(git grep -c '') | grep '^>' | cut -d : -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Breaking it down:

- `git grep -c ''` prints the names and line counts of each file in the repository. Adding the `-I` option makes the command ignore binary files.
- `diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)` uses process substitution to provide `diff` with named pipes through which the output of `cmd1` and `cmd2` are sent.
- The `grep` and `cut` commands are used to extract the filenames from the output of `diff`.

Comment: To deal with whitespace in file names correctly, you can change the `c` flag to `l` like so: `diff <(git grep -Il '' "$commit") <(git grep -l '' "$commit") | grep '^>' | cut -d':' -f2-`

Comment: How would you pipe this command to list get the file size of each file?

Comment: I got it, just use `| xargs du -ch {} +`

Comment: How could we change this to a history version of the command ? That is to say get all the binary files that once existed in the repo history?

Answer (score 16):

A simplified solution based on the answer of @jangler (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690662/808101)

```
comm -13 <(git grep -Il '' | sort -u) <(git grep -al '' | sort -u)
```

Explanation:

1. `git grep`

   - `-l` Ask to only print the filename of file matching the pattern `''` (which should match with every line of every file)
   - `-I` This option makes the command ignore binary files
   - `-a` This option force to process binary files as if they were text
2. `sort -u` Sort the result of the grep, since `comm` only process sorted files
3. `comm -13` List the files that are unique to the 2nd list (the `git grep` list with all files including the binary ones)

Comment: Add " | xargs du -c | sort -g" to find the biggest files and the total space in binaries

Answer (score 9):

Here is the same script for Windows using PowerShell:

```
$textFiles = git grep -Il .
$allFiles = git ls-files

foreach ($line in $allFiles){
    if ($textFiles -notcontains $line) {
        $line;
    }
}
```

Or in the short form:

```
$textFiles = git grep -Il .
git ls-files | where { $textFiles -notcontains $_ }
```

That takes `O(n^2)` to complete, and this is faster approach using hashtables:

```
$files = @{}
git ls-files | foreach { $files[$_] = 1 }
git grep -Il . | foreach { $files[$_] = 0 }
$files.GetEnumerator() | where Value -EQ 1 | sort Name | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

That takes `O(n)` to complete.

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -Fvxf <(git grep -Il '') <(git grep -al '')
```

Explanation:

- `git grep -Il ''`: list all non-empty regular files that git considers as text. See also: [How to list all text (non-binary) files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/how-to-list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-a-git-repository/24350112#24350112)
- `git grep -al ''`: list all non-empty regular files, including binary ones
- `grep -Fvxf`: select lines from file 2 that don't appear on file 1, therefore only the non-empty files that Git considers as binary. See: [How to remove the lines which appear on file B from another file A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

To also consider files added with `git add` but not yet committed:

```
grep -Fvxf <(git grep --cached -Il '') <(git grep --cached -al '')
```

Or you chould do a for loop on `git ls-files` with [How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text)

Tested on Git 2.16.1 with [this test repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-file-types/tree/f82d2d477a552d5fd8dab521f78a79390eb8927e).

Comment: This one includes submodules in the list

Answer (score 1):

Fast, easy, not sure how accurate:

`git ls-files -eol`

Anything tagged `i/-text` is likely treated as a binary file.

Comment: `git ls-files --eol`